# How do I attach an object to specific trackers?

Tags: camera, eevee-render-engine, tracking

I have been sitting and trying to solve these problems for ~6 hours, but to no avail.

- I tracked my **image sequence** with the default **Detect Features** button and added my own trackers, but object in my scene reacts only to **Detect Features** trackers.
- In addition, on some frames, it "leaps" to some positions for no reason.

Why is this happening?

Comment: The first thing is probably because you didn’t select your own trackers when you tracked. The second is probably solving errors because it didn’t have enough trackers to work with. However, if a tracker really is following the exact same point on an object, it will not generate errors. More trackers just creates more precision. Are you trying to track an object that bends during the video clip? Tracking expects it to be one solid object and the same points being tracked for each tracker.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard I think I tracked manual trackers [screenshot](https://ibb.co/Gt5CsV2), and yes, the object has to rotate

Comment: I said bend, not rotate.